# Fatal error: Call to undefined function media_include_browser_js()

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

When i want to make a slider for my Drupal website i always get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function media_include_browser_js()
```

Does someone know how i can solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

In the new media module the function media_include_browser_js() was replaced by function media_browser_js(), so if you change line 361(httpdocs/modules/media_gallery.module) on the media gallery module from

"media_include_browser_js();"

to

"media_browser_js();"

Comment: I have this in  problem in the art_revolution module. I changed the line but it didn't work.